# How to recreate xcode's connections inspector view

Tags: xcode, macos, nsview, inspector

I was wonder how I would go about creating something similar to the connections inspector view in the utilities panel in Xcode. The only thing I can see that looks similar is an Outline View or Source List but I don't know how to modify them to get the look in the screenshot below. Can somebody point me to a tutorial or something to help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I wanted by using JUInspectorView from here: https://github.com/JustSid/JUInspectorView

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you are looking for is some kind of customized panel object.  Apple has a good explanation of all of their UI elements (including panel) at [this webpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Windows/Windows.html).

Are you looking for a more low-level, code-based kind of tutorial?

Comment: I looked at the website you linked and didn't find anything that looked like my screenshot. I guess what I am asking is, if it is some sort of custom control, can somebody point me to a tutorial or somewhere to get me started in creating it.